# Use cookie to skip landing page

Tags: php, html, cookies, session-cookies

I have a landing page that I would like viewers to see when first arriving at //domain.com. Then, if they have been to the site before the browser would automatically skip the landing page and take them directly to //domain.com/main.html

What is the best approach to do this?

Comment: You just described the solution: set a cookie, if the cookie exists, redirect to the main page. Do you have a specific problem in implementing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were you, I would actually re-direct if they *haven't* seen the page the first time. It creates a more intuitive URL.

Either way, strictly speaking, you want to use `setcookie` the first time that the person visits the site, and then test to see if the value exists in `$_COOKIE` upon return. Realistically, you probably want:

1. Redirect if cookie not present
2. Link on landing page re-directs them to a page which sets the cookie.
3. Page which sets the cookie re-directs them to the actual main page.

Why do you want to set the value after the use clicks a link? Well, that way you can *force* them to actually look at the page before continuing, and I think that is more what you want.

Your redirect might look like:

```
if( !isset( $_COOKIE[ 'seen_landing_page' ] ) )
{
    header( 'Location: <other page>' );
    die();
}
// do whatever else here.
```

You can then have a simple pass-through page:

```
setcookie('seen_landing_page',TRUE);
header( 'Location: <your main page>' );
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the re-direct! Def the way to go

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
// index.php
if ( !isset($_COOKIE["been_here"]))
      setcookie("been_here",true);
else
      header("Location: main.html");
```